# Waiting for object to bind in CORBA Naming Service

Tags: java, corba

I would like to wait for a server to bind himself into the CORBA Naming Service.
Firstly I tried to use the following code, which is polling the Naming Service

```
Object expectedObj = null;
do
{
   try { expectedObj = ncRef.resolve_str("expectedToBeInNameService"); } 
   catch (NotFound e) {}
   Thread.sleep(2000);
} while(expectedObj == null;
```

My biggest problem is that this blocking. What is the easiest way to wait for it non-blocking?

Comment: What do you want to do while waiting for that object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wait in another thread and use a callback to notify the "original" thread or object that the request to the naming service was resolved.

```
class WaitThread extends Thread {
    CallBackObj callback;

    public WaitThread(CallBackObj callback) {
      this.text = callback;
      // assume CORBA stuff initiated here
    }

    public void run() {
      Object expectedObj = null;
      do
      {
         try { expectedObj = ncRef.resolve_str("expectedToBeInNameService"); } 
         catch (NotFound e) {}
         Thread.sleep(2000);
      } while(expectedObj == null;
      callback.notifyMethodExample();
    }
  }
```

The caller has to implement the interface CallBackObj and will create this thread by

```
WaitThread wt = new WaitThread(this);
wt.start();


interface CallBackObj {
 void notifyMethodExample();

}
```

Comment: Could you give a code sample? I'm not familiar in java threading.